# Live AR in music performance

Tags: performing, sound, musicology

What does it mean by Live AR in music performance? Sometimes, they also put it as Live AR mic open in the setlist/cue sheet of the live music performance/concert.

Comment: You’ll have to either tell us what AR stands for or give us at least one example of exactly where you’ve seen this.

Comment: Hi. I've seen this on a snapshot of live music performance's cue sheet.

Comment: Likely Audience Reaction mic, what you use for capturing applause, sing along or room sound.

Comment: 'AR' can also mean 'All Recorded', as in, lip-synced. But that wouldn't seem to make sense in the context of 'Live AR mic'.

Comment: thanks for the response! i guess when they put Live AR + mic open, it means lipsync but the mic open and we can still hear sound or voice from it.

Comment: Aha - so does that meaning of AR make sense in your context? If so I'll add it as an answer for future reference.

Comment: Yep because the other answers are more related to audience, not on-stage environment.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you saw the cue for the Audience Reaction mic. When recording live performance you often want to include the applause in the mix. Mics are set over the audience to separate tracks for mixing.  Also used for the Laugh Track on Television shows.

Comment: A 'laugh track' is the exact opposite of a mic over a live audience!

Comment: Shows often record the live audience to record the laughter, and have been since the early days of broadcast recording. In the recording mix, that recorded track is sometimes called the "laugh track". The use of a pre-recorded laugh track is named after it.

Comment: Yeah, both ways happen.  Not much point in arguing over labelling.

Answer (score 0):

In this context it usually refers to a microphone that's dedicated to picking up any audience response to the performance.